# C# virtual generic method call causes VS 2013 debugger to crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

am running into a strange issue when debugging the following code;

```
List<int> entityIds = _syncEngine.SearchChangeTrackedEntity<int,Order>(syncGuid,
   SyncType.New, null, 1000);
```

The interface definition for this method is;

```
List<T> SearchChangeTrackedEntity<T,U>(Guid syncGuid,
   SyncType syncType, List<AdditionalCriterion> filters, int maxResults)
       where U : IChangeTrackedEntity;
```

And the class that implements the interface method definition is;

```
public virtual List<T> SearchChangeTrackedEntity<T, U>(Guid syncGuid,
   SyncType syncType, List<AdditionalCriterion> filters, int maxResults)
      where U : IChangeTrackedEntity
```

I'am running this code on a local IIS instance (Win 7). The debugger throws a "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger" "Unhandled win32 exception occored in w3wp.exe [7536]" exception when the entitlyIds list used later in the code.

The really odd thing is the code execute normally if the debugger is not running.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: What is the line of code that fails?  Is _syncEngine native code?  Could be that it is not marshalling the native result to List<int>.

Comment: The line of code that causes the debugger to crash is;

    if(syncGuid != Guid.Empty && entityIds != null && entityIds.Count > 0)

Intrestingly if you look at entityIds iv VS via the locals window you get the following message "Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'entityIds' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away."

Comment: This makes me even more suspicious of native code and a native to managed data marshaling issue. Do you have any native code in your app?

Comment: That would be my thought too, however the application is all fully managed CLR code.

Comment: With the information presented, I'm stumped.  It's likely code that is not shown that is causing the problem.  Does the problem occur the first time the if statement is executed?  Do you get the odd debugger message when stepping through the code or only when attaching after a crash?  If only after, try stepping through the code and looking for anything strange.

Answer (score 1):

So after a week I stumbled upon what appears to resolved this issue.

The fix was to set the flag "use managed compatibility mode" in Tools > Options > Debugger > General.

See: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/21/Visual-Studio-2013-Could-not-evaluate-Expression-Debugger-Abnormality